# How to delete readonly variable in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
$ mySite="superuser"
$ readonly mySite
$ unset mySite
bash: unset: mySite: cannot unset: readonly variable
```

How can we delete mySite, as it is a readonly variable?

Comment: As said below, there is a [thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397069) with answers, with and **without** GDB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't delete mySite. The whole point of the readonly command is to make it final and permanent (until the shell process terminates). If you need to change a variable, don't mark it readonly.

Answer (score 9):

[Walker Hale IV](/users/116969/walker-hale-iv)'s solution can be expressed in a much shorter fashion using options available in more recent versions of `gdb`:

```
gdb --batch-silent --pid=$$ --eval-command='call unbind_variable("mySite")'
```

Again, this is **dark magic** that should be kept well away from production environments.

Comment: Got error: `'unbind_variable' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type`.  The declared return type is `int` ([github.com](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/f3a35a2d601a55f337f8ca02a541f8c033682247/variables.h)). **Success** after adding `(int)`: `gdb --batch-silent --pid=$$ --eval-command='call (int) unbind_variable("mySite")'`

Comment: It's not _just_ dark magic, it's very brittle magic, too. As it appears to rely on having a non-stripped version of Bash or at least matching symbols installed. This isn't a default on most systems on which I work.

Answer (score 3):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21294582/642372

This is **dark magic**. It uses `gdb` to tell the `bash` process to clear the variable by calling an internal C function.

```
mySite="superuser"
readonly mySite
gdb -n <<EOF >>/dev/null 2>&1
attach $$
call unbind_variable("mySite")
detach
quit
EOF
```

You should **never** have this in production. I have it in my .bashrc.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in shell. How can I make this work with sh?

Comment: @NickPodratz different shell, different functions. You'd have to consult specifically the source code of your shell and try to find the function that restricts `unset`-ting any readonly or -- as is done above -- one that would be called _after_ the check and outright unbinds the variable. That's why this is a very brittle "solution" indeed.